# Binary Classification for 1-feature Time Series Data using LSTM

Tags: time-series, classification, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm a beginner for **RNN**.

My current interest is to use `LSTM` to implement a time series classification. I have seen many examples such as [MNIST classification](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/recurrent_network.py).

However, I try implementing `LSTM` (using **Tensorflow framework**) to model a binary classification for temperature trend prediction (i.e. up or down).

The followings are some details on my experiment setting.

**Dataset:**

The dataset (Daily minimum temperatures in Melbourne) was obtained from [here](https://datamarket.com/data/set/2324/daily-minimum-temperatures-in-melbourne-australia-1981-1990#!ds=2324&display=line) with 3650 observations. I divided the data into windows with length 10; therefore, this will produce 3640 instances. And their corresponding labels are one-hot vectors representing the trend of the next value of the last value of the window, i.e. [1, 0] or [0, 1] in case of increasing or decreasing respectively.

For example, the dataset contains

```
1984/7/30,10

1984/7/31,10.6

1984/8/1,11.5

1984/8/2,10.2

1984/8/3,11.1

1984/8/4,11

1984/8/5,8.9

1984/8/6,9.9

1984/8/7,11.7

1984/8/8,11.6

1984/8/9,9

1984/8/10,6.3

1984/8/11,8.7

1984/8/12,8.5

1984/8/13,8.5

1984/8/14,8

1984/8/15,6
```

...

Two possible training window would be

```
(1) [10, 10.6, 11.5, 10.2, 11.1, 11, 8.9, 9.9, 11.7, 11.6] and label: [0, 1],
(2) [10.6, 11.5, 10.2, 11.1, 11, 8.9, 9.9, 11.7, 11.6, 9] and label: [0, 1],
(3) ...
```

**The problem:** My problem is that the model produces the outputs with accuracy wiggling around 49-50% accuracy. **So my question is "does it make sense to build a binary classification model having structure like above mentioned?"**.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.